# VITE REACT TYPESCRIPT XLSX Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/xlsx.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, xlsx, vite

**Trying to use the library xlsx with a project vite, reactjs, typescript but I still geting this error:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
> '/node_modules/.vite/deps/xlsx.js?v=823b22a3' does not provide an
> export named 'default'

```
import React from "react"
import * as XLSX from "xlsx"
import DragDropFile from "../File/DragDropFile"
import DataInput from "../File/DataInput"
import OutTable from "../File/OutTalbe"

export default class SheetJSApp extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [] /* Array of Arrays e.g. [["a","b"],[1,2]] */,
      cols: [] /* Array of column objects e.g. { name: "C", K: 2 } */,
    }
    this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this)
    this.exportFile = this.exportFile.bind(this)
  }
  handleFile(file: File) {
    /* Boilerplate to set up FileReader */
    const reader = new FileReader()
    const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      /* Parse data */
      const bstr = e.target?.result
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: rABS ? "binary" : "array" })
      /* Get first worksheet */
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0]
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname]
      console.log(rABS, wb)
      /* Convert array of arrays */
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 })
      /* Update state */
      this.setState({ data: data, cols: make_cols(ws["!ref"]) })
    }
    if (rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  }
  exportFile() {
    /* convert state to workbook */
    const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.state.data)
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new()
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS")
    /* generate XLSX file and send to client */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "sheetjs.xlsx")
  }
```

[image: Screenshot of ERROR from CHROM DEV TOOLS]

> **vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      esmExternals: true,
    },
  },
})
```

**

> packge.json

**

```
  "resolutions": {
    "**/react-element-to-jsx-string": "14.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no default export, use this instead:

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx"
```

Comment: Code is already like this. Doesn't work

Comment: @Fideles Show updated screenshot of the error

Comment: Screenshot updated!

Comment: Import in the image is not `import * as XLSX from "xlsx"`, it's `import XLSX from "xlsx"`

Comment: In the code is {import * as XLSX from "xlsx"}  but at the dev tools shows {import XLSX from "xlsx"}

Comment: I'm wondering if it worth quit with vite and go to create-react-app

Comment: It sounds like a cache or service worker.  Go to the `application` tab and click `clear site data`

Comment: Konrad I'v done it but it still getting the same error

Comment: And the same code is been shown at dev tools

Comment: Weird, sounds like if you didn't save or edit a wrong file

Comment: The same code works here, with javscript instead of typescript => https://codesandbox.io/s/xlsx-react-demo-34ft7?file=/src/App.js:4261-4896